# Scroll Effect JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am try to create a website that has a menu with a little bar under it showing where you are. And when you click one of the bars in looks like the content is scrolling left and the new content is coming from the right! How could I achieve this with jquery or something else?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to use the system of several floated objects within two nested wrapper divs, one with a fixed width and overflow:hidden, and the other with a width large enough to accommodate all of the inner elements.

Then slide the inner wrapper to the left.  Pop off the first element and move it to the back of the queue.

Here is a jsfiddle demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/karnage/wpm4E/